# How to find my static address from CheatEngine in C# with Memory functions

Tags: c#, windows, memory, offset

So I figured out a static address of my ping in TeamSpeak 3 with a cheat engine.
The adress is "Qt5Gui.dll"+005F2E58 so module Qt5Gui.dll + offset of 0x005F2E58

With Cheat Engine it's not a problem to get the ping value after restarting the application.

Now I tried to find this address in C# using memory functions but I'm not getting my address.

The Wanted Adress is: 16CE3AB92E40549592
My Programm gets me: 14072403

How to find the right address like in cheat engine?

My getModule function:

```
 static IntPtr getModule(String processName, String moduleName)
        {
            Process[] ProcessList = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName);
            IntPtr BaseAddress = IntPtr.Zero;

            if (ProcessList.Length > 0)
            {
                Process process = ProcessList[0];

                foreach (System.Diagnostics.ProcessModule Module in process.Modules)
                {
                    if (Module.ModuleName.Contains(moduleName))
                    {
                        BaseAddress = Module.BaseAddress;
                        break;
                    }

                }

            }

            return BaseAddress;
        }
```

Main Function:

```
String process = "ts3client_win64";

IntPtr handle = getProcessHandle(process);

if (!handle.Equals(new IntPtr(1337)))
    {
      IntPtr qtGui = getModule(process, "Qt5Gui.dll");
      int pingOffset = 0x005F2E58;
      IntPtr pingAdress = IntPtr.Add(qtGui, pingOffset);

      Int64 finalPingAdress = pingAdress.ToInt64();

      MessageBox.Show("Ping Adress: " + finalPingAdress);
     }
     else
     {
        MessageBox.Show("Process Not Found!");
     }
```

[image: Image of CheatEngine + my tool]

Comment: Are you sure the address shown in Cheat Engine is the actual current address? Did you step through the code to make sure you're looking at the right process and module? You could try verifying the module address in a debugger too. There's nothing obviously wrong with your code so far, and the two addresses are completely different (except for the offset), so I'm not sure there's anything we can do to help you. Did you try reading the memory from the target process? Also, why are you expecting `16CE3AB92E40549592`? You should get `0x16CE5116840` (`1567211219008` in decimal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To walk multilevel pointers using modulename.dll + 0xDEADC0DE scheme base addresses you can use my code

```c#
public static IntPtr FindDMAAddy(IntPtr hProc, IntPtr ptr, int[] offsets)
{
    var buffer = new byte[IntPtr.Size];
    foreach (int i in offsets)
    {
        ReadProcessMemory(hProc, ptr, buffer, buffer.Length, out var read);

        ptr = (IntPtr.Size == 4)
        ? IntPtr.Add(new IntPtr(BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0)), i)
        : ptr = IntPtr.Add(new IntPtr(BitConverter.ToInt64(buffer, 0)), i);
    }
    return ptr;
}

public static IntPtr GetModuleBaseAddress(Process proc, string modName)
{
    IntPtr addr = IntPtr.Zero;

    foreach (ProcessModule m in proc.Modules)
    {
        if (m.ModuleName == modName)
        {
            addr = m.BaseAddress;
            break;
        }
    }
    return addr;
}
```

Here is an example of me using this code to do what you want to do

```
Process process;

process = Process.GetProcessesByName("ac_client")[0];

var hProc = OpenProcess(0x001F0FFF, false, process.Id);

var modBase = GetModuleBaseAddress(process, "ac_client.exe");

var addr = FindDMAAddy(hProc, (IntPtr)(modBase + 0x10f4f4), new int[] { 0x374, 0x14, 0 });

Console.WriteLine("0x" + addr.ToString("X"));
Console.ReadKey();
```